# Update View from Click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to update a date dynamically from a user clicking a forward or backward button, but can't seem to figure out how to make the data change from the view.

The variable `date` changes but not from the browser.

< July 31, 2017 >

[Example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuJxM.png)

EDIT: I had originally put my methods inside the constructor (I don't have it that way in my code, but rather me mistyping it in the question here)

**App Component**

```
    export class AppComponent {
       date: Date;

       constructor () {
         this.date = new Date();
      }
      dateForward() {
        this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);
      }

      dateBack() {
        this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() - 1);
      }                
   }
```

**HTML Template**

```
<i (click)="dateBack()" class="fa fa-chevron-left" ></i>
<a>{{date | date:'MMM d, y'}}</a>
<i  (click)="dateForward()" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside not puting your methods inside your constructor you should pay attention to change detection and immutability
`this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1)` will not trigger change detection, to enforce that you need `this.date = new Date(this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1));`, the change detector will notice the change only if you change to a different object entirely and not when you set an object properties, same thing with arrays

```
 constructor() {
    this.date = new Date();
 }

 dateForward() { 
    this.date = new Date(this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1));
 }

 dateBack() {
   this.date = new Date(this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() - 1));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not put your functions in your constructor. Instead, you should create methods in your class, this will allow you to call them in your HTML template.

```
public date: Date;

constructor() {
  this.date = new Date();
}

public dateForward = () => this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);

public dateBack = () => this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**methods should not be inside constructor**

```
date :Date;
  constructor() {
      this.date = new Date();
   }


    dateForward() {
       this.date = new Date(this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1));
    }
      dateBack() {
       this.date = new Date(this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() -1 ));
      }
```

Working [Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/kONG4XDHc1K5pq18t7L7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

in `angular` inside controller you can define a `$scope` variable lets say you call that variable `date`.

e.g. `$scope.date = new Date().getDate();`

Then inside your html you can access it

```
<div> {{date}} </div>
```

And whenever you click your call to action buttons you can change the value of this `$scope` variable and as soon as it will change the value of HTML will be updated automatically.

You can run the following code to see the example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

   <h1>{{date | date:'MMM d, y'}}</h1>

   <a href="#" ng-click="dateBack();">Back</a>
   <a href="#" ng-click="dateForward();">Forward</a>
  </div>


  <script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.date = new Date();
       
       $scope.dateBack = function(){
        $scope.date.setDate($scope.date.getDate() - 1);
       };
       
       $scope.dateForward = function(){
        $scope.date.setDate($scope.date.getDate() + 1);
       };
   });
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure this is relevant for my issue? I'm using angular 4 whereas this seems to apply to angularjs. Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but the answer that Kld provided solved my issue.